# Dynamic spring properties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi guys is there any good examples of changing spring properties files content dynamically? I would really appreciate it if you could give me some example or link.

Thanks alot

Comment: More context - explain what you mean.  I'm not aware that it's done, because wiring relationships isn't that dynamic.  But some context from you might make it clearer what you have in mind.

Comment: @duffymo Hey, what I want to do is to give users ability to change some parameters like changing the website logo text. I want to store it in a properties file so when the website loads it will get the website logo text from that properties file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could use [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html) .It uses `java.util.Properties` instances as its internal data structure for messages.

Also , as the name suggests , this class supports reloading of properties files through the [cacheSeconds](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html#setCacheSeconds%28int%29) setting, and also through programmatically clearing the properties cache. Note that since application servers do typically cache all files loaded from the classpath, you have to put properties files outside of your classpath (`WEB-INF/classes`) or it'll be cached and won't work.

---

**References / examples / links**

- http://techdive.in/spring/spring-internationalization-i18n
- http://www.jroller.com/raible/entry/spring_mvc_s_reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource

Answer (score -2):

Actually, spring support ${variable} in configration file like below

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="locations">
<list>               
<value>file:${XXX}/XXX.properties</value>
<value>file:${XXX}/YYY.properties</value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't what I want. I want to change the spring properties file's content dynamically. Sorry if I wasn't clear about my question.